# How to make Path a button android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a portion of my imageview clickable using a Path, how do I do that? I tried to search for solutions but I just can't seem to find it

I tried to use RectF and ComputeBounds for the path but the bounds always becomes incorrect, I tried to draw the bounds with a drawRect and it displays a Flat rectangle while my PATH is a slanted rectangle. I don't know how to fix it please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.